# Wagtail CMS send image URL over API request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, wagtail

I am using wagtail headless as a CMS for my front-end application. Everything is working fine so far, but I can not get my images into my front-end application when calling the API.

Here is the model I am working with right now, I am using streamfield too:

```
from django.db import models

from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.core.fields import StreamField
from wagtail.core import blocks
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, StreamFieldPanel
from wagtail.images.blocks import ImageChooserBlock as DefaultImageChooserBlock
from wagtail.api import APIField

class ImageChooserBlock(DefaultImageChooserBlock):
    def get_api_representation(self, value, context=None):
        if value:
            return {
                'id': value.id,
                'title': value.title,
                'large': value.get_rendition('width-1000').attrs_dict,
                'thumbnail': value.get_rendition('fill-120x120').attrs_dict,
            }

class HomePage(Page):
    body = StreamField([
        ('heading', blocks.CharBlock(classname="full title")),
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
        ('image', ImageChooserBlock()),
    ],)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('body'),
    ]

    api_fields = [
        APIField('body'),
    ]
```

I got the override code for `ImageChooserBlock` here : [Wagtail getting/generating image urls from JSON api or directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45732594/wagtail-getting-generating-image-urls-from-json-api-or-directly)

This no longer seems to be working, I am still getting a response from API as follows:

```
"title": "now",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "image",
            "value": 1,
            "id": "f5714257-bf5d-469b-9b4f-875212ec8d8d"
        }
```

I need the URL so I can display them in my application.

Any other ideas? I can't find any info about this anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I post a solution to a similar problem here.

[How to get image url or download url of images in pages API where image is created by a streamfield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58266648/how-to-get-image-url-or-download-url-of-images-in-pages-api-where-image-is-creat/58399640#58399640)

Your general approach looks right.
Are you using

```
/api/v2/pages/?type=home.HomePage&fields=body
```

For you API call?

Comment: Yes, I made sure to request /api/v2/pages/?type=home.HomePage&fields=body. Still does not work. I have dug in the source code for a few hours and it looks like this code should work to overwrite ImageChooserBlock, then streamfield writes the content serialized into the database, then re-used by the api call.

I tried having def get_api_representation() return something simple like:

def get_api_representation(self, value, context=None):
        if True:
            return {
                'title': 'test',
            }